# Create TArray dynamically in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal

Suppose I have a `UObject` class with a `TArray` saved as `UPROPERTY`. Is there a way to create `TArray` dynamically and then set `Objects` to a newly created array (see code below)?

```
UCLASS(BlueprintType, Blueprintable)
class SOME_API UClassA : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:    
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    TArray<UObject*> Objects;    
};
```

`NewObject` seems to raise a compilation error when trying to create `TArray`

```
UClassA* ObjA = NewObject<UclassA>();
TArray<UObject*>* NewArray = NewObject<TArray<UObject*>>(); // this raises compilation error
ObjA->Objects = *NewArray;
```

Error:

```
Error C2039 : 'StaticClass': is not a member of 'TArray<UObject *,FDefaultAllocator>'
Reference C2039 : see declaration of 'TArray<UObject *,FDefaultAllocator>'
Reference C2039 : see reference to function template instantiation 'T *NewObject<TArray<UObject *,FDefaultAllocator>>(UObject *)' being compiled
          with
          [
              T=TArray<UObject *,FDefaultAllocator>
          ]
```

Can I create `TArray` with simple c++ `new` will this work? Will the Garbage Collector keep track of new array instead of the `Objects` array created in the constructor?

Edit:
I intend to create both `TArray` and contained `UObject`s dynamically. And I want the UE Garbage Collector to see them. This is meant the to be the only place they are stored.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Add` or `Emplace` to add elements to the `TArray` if `UClassA` inherits from `UObject` (which should also have a `virtual` destructor):

```cpp
TArray<UObject*> Objects;
//...
Objects.Add(new UClassA);
```

If you also want to create a single `TArray` dynamically, you could store it in a `std::unique_ptr`:

```cpp
#include <memory>
//...
std::unique_ptr<TArray<UObject*>> Objects;
//...
Objects = std::make_unique<TArray<UObject*>>();
```

Comment: Sorry, the question is about dynamically creating `TArray` and another prerequisite is for the `UObject`s it stores to be seen by the garbage collector.  I want to create both `TArray` and `UObject`s dynamically

Comment: @Unicorn Ok, I thought that was a mistake, but I clearly misunderstood that. I updated the answer.

Comment: I don't believe it is enough for GC system to see that this dynamic array holds references to UObjects. These objects may be deleted by GC because it does not see the dynamically created Array, no?

Comment: @Unicorn If I understand the UE documentation correctly you'll need to mark the `UObject`s ready for GC. So if you you could store `unique_ptr`s with a custome deleter to mark all of them automatically when the `TArray` is destroyed. I'm still not 100% sure why you'd want do allocate the ´TArray` dynamically though.

Answer (score 0):

`NewObject<UClassA>()` has already created a `TArray<UObject*>` with dynamic storage duration, as a member subobject of `*ObjA`. You don't need to `new` a second one.

The garbage collector does't deal with members, those are destructed by the destructor of the enclosing object.

If you want to fill a new `TArray` and then assign to `ObjA->Objects`, then you can use a local variable.

Comment: This `Objects` array is meant to be the only place these `UObjects` are stored so that they won't be garbage collected. They will also be created dynamically. Also the intent was to create the `TArray` elsewhere in a factory. Is there a way to create an array dynamically and still have it referenced for UE GC system? I mean I need to mark the `TArray` with `UPROPERTY`. I maybe could have used pointer to the `TArray` in the body of `UClassA` but the objects it will contain will not be seen by GC would they?

Comment: I made an edit of the question in an attempt to clarify this

Comment: @Unicorn Why? It's *preferable* to have it be a data member. You already *have* marked `Objects` with `UPROPERTY`

Comment: Why what? And what do you mean preferable? You need to mark TArray as UPROPERTY so that it's containing objects will be counted for GC. I want new array created dynamically to be visible for GC also

Comment: @Unicorn At the moment, `~UClassA()` destroys `Objects`. You don't need it to be garbage collected.

Comment: Ok. It may be confusing. The code of `UClassA` is not essential. `UClassA` contains the TArray in *any* form. What I need to do is to create the TArray dynamically and I need that dynamically created array to be visible to GC system so that the `UObject`s it contains would be referenced somewhere (in *that* dynamically created array) and not be destroyed. This will be the only place they are referenced 100% during the game. The question is how to create a dynamic array which GC system sees. I know I can just populate the one that is hard coded in the class. The question is not about that

Comment: @Unicorn No, The code of `UClassA` **is** essential. At the moment you *do* have a dynamically created `TArray`, because it is a member of a dynamically created `UClassA`. It can be a `UPROPERTY` *because* it is a data member